# Difference between mat and md in angular 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am new to angular2. I would like to know the difference between using md and mat in angular2. I tried googling but cant find the answers that I expect. I am using Angular 2 in Visual Studio 2015. Can someone please help me with the answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mat- and md- are prefixes in two different versions of angular materials. 
"md" prefix is deprecated from material version 2.0.0-beta.11.
[deprecation-of-md-prefix](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix)